# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - SELECT ALL from two INNER JOIN tables without duplicate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and have tried using GROUP BY and WHERE statements, I have also tried to use DISTINCT but am not sure if I am putting these in the wrong places or what. I've tried several different way, several different times with no luck. Either I get an error or I get duplicates.

**Here's the problem:**

```
/*
JOIN the Orders and OrderDetails tables to display all available fields
about an order; however, only display the order number one time.
Display an additional column labeled SubTotal that will multiply
the quoted price by the quantity ordered.
*/
```

**Here's what I've got so far minus the non-working failed attempted bits:**

```
SELECT *,
       quotedPrice * quantityOrdered As [SubTotal]
FROM Orders INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.orderNumber = OrderDetails.orderNumber
```

- I tried to put GROUPBY orderNumber
- I tried to make another row in the select statement for DISTINCT orderNumber just above the row with the asterisk(all).
- I tried to use WHERE Orders.orderNumber = OrderDetails.orderNumber

I've not been using SQL for very long, only about four months now. I'm still learning.

Comment: Could you include the table definition of both tables?

Comment: Some examples of returned rows with the “duplicate columns” you are talking about would also be useful.

Comment: In addition, please include the output which your attempted query gives.

Comment: Have you got any sample data? Just reading the question, it seems like its  just asking to to show it, so, instead of select * , qouted price you need to just specify the coloumns you are after, only showing orderNumber once. You can go select orders.column, orderdetails. * to make it easier

Comment: The two duplicate columns are the primary or foreign key? Not sure which it is called. They're the columns that the tables are joined on. The OrderNumber column appears in both tables because it's how they're linked. Unfortunately, it's also the reason why that column shows up twice and I don't know how to fix that.

OrderDetails has:
OrderNumber | ProductNumber | QuotedPrice | QuantityOnHand

Orders has:
OrderNumber | ShipDate | OrderDate | CustomerID | EmployeeID

I believe this database is called Northwind Database.

Comment: No, the columns appear because you have `*` in the select list. Remove the `*` and add the columns, one by one, that you want in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like the following. Because I don't know your column names the following is more like a guess. Notice that I have used table aliases O for Orders and OD for OrderDetails. This makes it easier to be specific about which columns to display. Also notice (importantly for your question) that I have only specified OrderNumber once (the other reference is commented out).

```
SELECT
  O.OrderNumber,
  O.ColName2
  O.ColName3,
  O.ColName4,
  O.ColName5,
  ... --etc
  --OD.OrderNumber,
  OD.ColNam1,
  OD.ColName2,
  ... --etc
  OD.quotedPrice,
  OD.quantityOrdered,
  OD.quotedPrice * OD.quantityOrdered AS [SubTotal]
FROM
  Orders O
  INNER JOIN OrderDetails OD
    ON O.orderNumber = OD.orderNumber
```

BTW It is rarely good practice to use the * character to list all columns even though it seems convenient to do so. This is one example where it can be bad.